# Equivalent of ISNULL in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an equivalent of SQL's ISNULL function in Google Apps Script? If not, how to implement it?

The goal is to assume zero if there's blank cell in a range while doing some calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Apps Script accesses the values in a range where some cells are blank, the content of blank cells is represented by empty string `''`, not by `null` value. You can replace these with 0s like this

```
function zeroIfNull(a) {
  return a === '' ? 0 : a;
}
```

or, if you want to do this within some range of more than one cell,

```
function zeroIfNull(array) {
  return array.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(element) {
      return element === '' ? 0 : element;
    });
  });
}
```